# Primefaces p:inplace component: how to read state in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, primefaces, edit-in-place

How to access the state of **PrimeFaces p:inplace** component in **Javascript**?

I need to check if the component is in state *inline* or not, in order to call `toggle()`function when needed... AFAIK `toggle()` can only **change** the state and not set the state to desired value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you got something like thisL

```
<p:inplace id="basic" widgetVar="myWidget">  
    <p:inputText value="Edit Me" />  
</p:inplace>
```

You can check if the inplace was *opened* with the help of the `widgetVar` and jQuery , like this

```
jQuery(myWidget.content).is(":visible")
```

Or you can check it with the `:visible` selector and the id of the inplace :

append `_display` to your inplace element id to check if the editor **wasn't open yet**

append `_content` to your inplace element id to check if the editor **was already open**

```
jQuery("#basic_display").is(":visible")

jQuery("#basic_content").is(":visible")
```

you can check it in browser console in the showcase [Primefaces Inplace](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/inplace.jsf)

Comment: But it's a hack too, and the blinking would occur... However functioning

Comment: the check itself does no blinking at all... its just checking the state... its no doing any action...

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved it with checking the CSS **display** value of *ui-inplace-display* and *ui-inplace-content* elements:

```
            $('.ui-inplace-display').filter(function(){
                return $(this).css('display') == 'inline';
            }).toggle();
            $('.ui-inplace-content').filter(function(){
                return $(this).css('display') == 'none';
            }).toggle();
```

However, for me it's more a hack that a solution, so I'd expect something more elegant, such as a state in dedicated attribute of JavaScript object, or at least dedicated CSS class for that.